# Finatra - reading a request in chunks

Tags: json, scala, finatra

Here's my use case:
I am implementing a finatra server, that should be able to receive many concurrent large requests.
These requests have a large body (several megabytes) comprised of many small json objects, concatenated.

I'd like to avoid loading the entire request body into memory. I'm looking for a way to read the request body in chunks, and use a json parser that supports this sort of async parsing.

In node.js this can be achieved by using the jsonp package (see the example - https://github.com/jaredhanson/node-jsonsp/blob/master/examples/twitter-stream/app.js).

Can I do something similar with finatra (and how)?

PS - 
I also posted the question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/finatra-users/qJyb-SWsXdI), but got no answer so far.

Comment: you might want to check out the new and idiomatic [http4s](http://http4s.org) library if you're interested in streaming and high performance.

Comment: Thanks. That looks really interesting. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Finatra. Finatra will not call your route until the entire request has been received and memorized into a ChannelBuffer. In addition, Finatra also reads the request as a single chunk so you cannot receive any body longer than ~2MB. Setting `com.twitter.finatra.config.maxRequestSize` to something higher than 2048 will cause it to crash at runtime.

I've switched to Play Framework using the `NettyServer` [embed](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaEmbeddingPlay) and "[String Interpolating Routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSirdRouter)" to retain a DSL similar to Finatra.